# Maximum value of sum of K partitioned subarrays

Tags: java, algorithm, partition

Given a subarray of an array, its value is the maximum of the elements it contains that appear an odd number of times.

I want to Partition an array into K sub arrays to maximize the sum of the subarray values.

E.g. if we have following array
5 6 6 3 9 with K=2

We could partition it as follows:
(5) + (6,6,3,9) = (5 + 9 => 14 )
(5,6) + (6,3,9) = ( 6 +9 => 15 )
(5,6,6) + (3,9) = ( 5 + 9 =>14 )
(5,6,6,3) + (9) = ( 5 + 9 => 14 )

I am able to do it the brute way but looking for an efficient algorithm. Could you please suggest something

Comment: where's the code you have tried?

Comment: where is your limit?

Comment: @saijb Probably, I am trying to convince myself about it.

Comment: oh i got your question now

Comment: pls add maximum value of K & max number of element in array

Comment: K will always be less than equal to number of elements in the array

Comment: how many number can be there?

Comment: solution depends on constraints.

Comment: I think the question is what other algorithms except for brute force could be used for solving the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm I see is quite easy. You need to find positions of K maximum values in the array and then divide array in the way that these positions are in different subarrays in the way that max value is included the odd number of times in each subarray. Need to specifically look into the last case. One of the options is trying to get the first one if K limit is reached.

So, for (6,6,6) and K=2 the algorithm should be:
Find 2 max elements (if K limit is reached, take the first K). In our case, it's first and second 6.
Then divide into subarrays (from max to nextMax-1)

```
(6) + (6,6) => 6
```

Quite an interesting case is (6,7,6,6) and K=3
The expected result is

```
(6) + (7,6) + (6) = 19
```

My algorithm doesn't cover that case

Pseudocode:

```
1. indexes = FindKMaxIndexes() // Use selection algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm, some variation to save indexes instead of elements values
2. reorder indexes from smallest to largest
3. i = 0
4. for each item in sorted indexes array
4.1 create subarray to include item (from i to current index)
4.2 i = current index + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the question seems like what the sum of maximum K number is. So just need to order by descending and sum the first K number.

Comment: why for k=5 answer 9

Comment: The max K does not fully cover the problem. For example, the expected result for (6,6,6) and K=2 is 6 and it couldn't be calculated by the algorithm to find K max elements

Comment: Another counter example is  [9,9,9,8] and k=2 will give you 17 and not 18

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, we can have `O(n^2 * k)` since if `f(i, k)` represents the maximum achievable up to `A[i]` with `k` parts, then:

```
f(i, k) = max(
  // include A[i] in previous part
  g(A[j..i]) + f(j - 1, k - 1),

  // don't include A[i] in previous part
  A[i] + f(i - 1, k - 1)
)
for all k <= j < i
where g(subarray) is the max element
in subarray that appears an odd number
of times
```

The question is how can we more efficiently pick which subarrays to test including `A[i]` against.